# What do the columns in SYS.USER$ represent?

Tags: oracle, oracle-9i

In the `SYS.USER$` view, what do the `CTIME`, `PTIME`, and `LTIME` columns represent?

Where can I find Oracle's documentation for this and other system views?

Comment: I could not find this information using Google or on Oracle's support website. Unfortunately, much of Oracle's documentation is poorly indexed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Test cases below show:

- `CTIME` is the date the user was created.
- `LTIME` is the date the user was last locked. (Note that it doesn't get `NULL`ed when you unlock the user).
- `PTIME` is the date the password was last changed.
- `LCOUNT` is the number of failed logins.

Here's the test code:

```
SQL> create user philtest identified by philtest;

User created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='HH24:MI:SS DD/MM/YYYY';

Session altered.

SQL> select ctime,ltime,ptime from user$ where name = 'PHILTEST';

CTIME               LTIME               PTIME
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
14:21:51 26/04/2012                     14:21:51 26/04/2012

SQL> alter user philtest account lock;

User altered.

SQL> select ctime,ltime,ptime from user$ where name = 'PHILTEST';

CTIME               LTIME               PTIME
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
14:21:51 26/04/2012 14:23:15 26/04/2012 14:21:51 26/04/2012

SQL> alter user philtest identified by foofoo;

User altered.

SQL> select ctime,ltime,ptime from user$ where name = 'PHILTEST';

CTIME               LTIME               PTIME
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
14:21:51 26/04/2012 14:23:15 26/04/2012 14:27:47 26/04/2012

SQL>
```

This isn't documented in the Oracle docs, as it's an internal data dictionary view. However, the `DBA_%`/`ALL_%`/`USER_%` views that sit on top of the `SYS.%` views are documented [here](http://www.oracle.com/pls/tahiti/tahiti.catalog_views).

I often find that doing a `DESC`ribe on one of the `DBA_%` views gives a good indication of what the underlying columns represent. The `DBA_%` views are often commented too.

Answer (score 2):

It is not intended that you use the internal tables like user$ directly. You should query the static ditionary views sys.dba_% instead of. These are well documented in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/toc.htm)

Hardcore Oracle freaks can read the comments in the file" $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/sql.bsq" or browse sites like [this one](http://www.ixora.com.au/q+a/)

Comment: I checked out `SYS.DBA_USERS` first, but it does not expose `PTIME` or `LCOUNT`, both of which are very useful for monitoring certain user behavior.

Comment: @Nick seeing as they are intentionally undocumented you shouldn't rely on them existing in future versions, nor assume that their behaviour is always what it seems to be